# Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1

Tags: mysql

Strange problem I can't seem to get my head around.  I have a table in a MySQL database with the following structure...

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblbaseprices` (
  `base_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `base_size` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `base_label` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `base_price_1a` float default NULL,
  `base_price_2a` float default NULL,
  `base_price_3a` float default NULL,
  `base_price_1b` float default NULL,
  `base_price_2b` float default NULL,
  `base_price_3b` float default NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`base_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=134 ;
```

The last base_id I have in there is 132.  I assume a couple of records have been deleted to auto_increment is set to 134, as you can see about.  I am trying to run the following SQL statement, and when I do, I get the error "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1".

```
INSERT INTO tblbaseprices (site_id, base_size, base_price_1a, base_price_2a, base_price_3a, base_price_4a) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '')
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you inseret empty strings into float/int columns?

Comment: What is `base_price_4a`? I don't see it in your `create table`.

Comment: @sapht It can be the reason of error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With you code I got this error - Unknown column 'base_price_4a' in 'field list'.
It means that you are trying to insert into another table (maybe in another schema), and that table has primary key INT and AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483647.

Comment: Good eye. @Doyley : Please check if you're showing us correct/current table structure!

Comment: Ah .. I posted a table from the wrong database, and there was an error in code posting to that table.  It was trying to generate an ID in php then post it to the auto increment column which caused it to max out.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 17):

```
2^31 − 1 = 2,147,483,647
```

[The number 2,147,483,647 is ... the maximum value for a 32-bit signed integer in computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#2147483647_in_computing)

Comment: Just as an addition to this answer, if you're using `int` as the primary, auto-increment column for a table, the above number is the maximum value you can have. Use `bigint` to go past this limitation.

Answer (score 6):

2147483647 is the largest int value for mysql. Just change the type from int to bigint.

Answer (score 2):

you've hit the 32-bit integer limit, thus preventing the auto increment from incrementing.  switching your pk to bigint with a higher column length should fix the issue.

Also, if your PK is never going to be negative, switching to an unsigned int should give you more space.

Comment: no, "Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 1", where key 1 is the primary key (EDIT: seems i made a bad assumption, and thought there was a bulk import happening...)

Comment: Also PK is an unsigned bigint apparently

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the auto_increment column to bigint instead of int, then the max value would be '9223372036854775807' or even '18446744073709551615' if you make it unsigned (no values below 0).

Change your Auto_Increment to the last id in the column so it is continued where it left off.

Be sure you do not delete auto_increment, otherwise it will continue to produce the error.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting empty strings into numerical columns. As far as I can see, you're also inserting into a column that does not exist in the schema. My guess is this has something to do with your error.

Comment: Why would that matter? According to the create table statement site_id is not a key at all.

Answer (score 1):

signed and unsigned issue

```
alter table tblbaseprices
modify column site_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL;
```

reference - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

- <strike>make sure unsigned for foreign key (in this case could be the `site_id`)</strike>
- it could be caused by trigger,
- there is no `int(11)`, the max it can go is `int(10)`
- there is no need to allow negative value for ID
- to be consistently using same data type for primary key

Comment: But why it manifests itself at AUTO_INCREMENT=134? The PK column is a bigint mind.

Comment: It only mention key 1, which I can think of is the foreign key

Comment: `Key 1` is the first key in table (there's no `key 0`) and this table has only one key anyway.

Comment: yup, true, another possibilities is caused by trigger

Comment: AFAIR you can't have BEFORE/AFTER INSERT trigger inserting into the same table on which it is defined... Would need to check that though.

Comment: Understood, there is nothing wrong on BIGINT data type, the only problematic column is the site_id, and the trigger can attempt to insert to another table

Comment: Indeed. Error message as provided does not mention table name

Answer (score 0):

Today I got the error `duplicate key 2147483647`

I think it came out when I tried to insert a record into database from PhpMyAdmin, while typing, I also tried to enter the key value and it was eider lower than the current `Next autoindex` or I tried to type something like `99999999999999` as the key field, and that caused it to set `Next autoindex` to maximum

Anyway, the erorr was caused because `Next autoindex` was `2147483647` for that table.
My table was empty so I fixed it by this query:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 0
```

**if your table contains data, then replace `0` with your maximum key plus `1`**

Answer (score 0):

it's a database issue. check your phpmyadmin > your DB > structure, your primary key should be setted in "bigint", not just "int"

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblbaseprices` (
  `base_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `base_size` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `base_label` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `base_price_1a` float default NULL,
  `base_price_2a` float default NULL,
  `base_price_3a` float default NULL,
  `base_price_1b` float default NULL,
  `base_price_2b` float default NULL,
  `base_price_3b` float default NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`base_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=134 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation of that is here: http://realtechtalk.com/Duplicate_entry_2147483647_for_key_PRIMARY_MySQL_Error_Solution-2015-articles

Essentially you are trying to insert a value larger than the maximum size an INT supports which is literally the number being given to you in the error.

If you are importing data than one of the fields contains a larger value than the INT size.  You could also modify your table to be a BIGINT which would take care of the issue as well (of course at the cost of extra disk space).

A common reason is that you are using some script generating large/random numbers.  You should add some check to make sure the size is the same or lower than that maximum INT size of 2147483647 and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate entry '57147-2147483647' for key 'app_user' [ INSERT INTO `user_lookup` (`user_id`, `app_id`, `app_user_id`, `special_offers`, `ip_address`) VALUES ('2426569', '57147', '4009116545', 1, 1854489853) ]