# Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I receive this error when trying to insert something in the DB.

> Error: (1467) Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

This is my table info:
Row Statistics

> Format    Compact Options     avg_row_length=620 checksum=1
>   delay_key_write=1 row_format=DYNAMIC Collation    utf8_general_ci Next
>   autoindex     52,267

how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Where is the PHP code that generates the error?

Comment: sql insert statement but it's not the problem as the code was working correctly before the server was crashed and recovering the DB  and importing it into new server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any chance the auto incremented value is exceeding it's limit?
What is your data type? and what is the current auto-incremented field's value?

[***Here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346934/mysql-failed-to-read-auto-increment-value-from-storage-engine) is a similar discussion. Please check if it helps!

You can try this once on the table:

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT =1
```

Comment: this can be caused by a negative auto_increment value being assigned.. an integer overflow on a signed field could cause this.

Comment: id is int(15) unsigned, The last inserted id is 52266

Comment: how may records and what storage engine are you using?

Comment: 13650 records .. storage engine: InnoDB

Comment: I did take a look on it before asking and it doesn't help.  @Mayukh

Comment: yes, of-course! checking it as per your given inputs :)

Comment: Try this:
ALTER TABLE `table_name`  AUTO_INCREMENT =1

Comment: but this will reset my id to 1 which means the next id will be 1, may be that will cause duplication issue after that? @MayukhRoy

Comment: I dont think this will reset your id to 1, It will remove AI key and set it back as per the last inserted row. I tested it on my box! Anyway, you have a crashed system! you may create a duplicate table and check on it.

Comment: again, if it doesn't work, try: 
ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 0
  .This will reset the auto_increment value to be the next value based on the highest existing value in the auto_increment column. Please let me know if any of these works, and which one :)

Comment: none of them worked :(

Comment: Also when I try to update row I get that error:
Got error -1 from storage engine

Comment: Well, I can not reproduce the error. It's getting very difficult for me to imagine and guess :(

Comment: I had the same issue and had to set the primary key, auto_increment column to `bigint` instead of `int`, which maxes out at **2,147,483,647**. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025153/duplicate-entry-2147483647-for-key-1